# Error Code - 13 Is Displayed When an Application Fails to Be Installed

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

When I download a my application from the Huawei AppGallery, a message is displayed indicating that the installation fails.

Opening the message and view the failure details.

The specific failure information is Conflicting Provider and Error Code is -13. In addition, the system displays the name of the application that conflicts with and the recommended solution. How can I solve this problem？

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a provider conflict occurs when you install an app, it is because an existing app has the same `ContentProvider`.

The `ContentProvider` feature interacts and shares data between processes, which determines that it must be globally unique. Once an app has registered a `ContentProvider` on the phone, the app installed later cannot use the same `ContentProvider`. Otherwise, the installation will fail.

The fix for this is to make sure that all `ContentProvider` names are kept unique, best practice is to make your package namespace part of the provider definition in your manifest.

For example:

```
<provider
    android:name="myapplication.android.hms.unity.provider.AnalyticsContentProvider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Confirm you package name is unique and has been definited in your ContentProvi der.

```html
<provider>
</provider>
```

Comment: What correspond the provider code snippet ? Also, I suggest you to explain more. You can read [answer].